# Dropdown list databind is not working after using(DataView dv = dt.DefaultView) block

Tags: c#, asp.net

I can't seem to figure out why this isn't working... 
I have two drop down lists.. The first one I'm binding to a DataView
 and the second one I want to bind it to the DataTable itself.
When I try to bind the second drop down list to the datatable outside of the DataView using block.. I doesn't populate the records...

Not sure why this is happening.. anyone have any ideas?
If I move the code to bind the second drop down list inside the using block of the DataView or before that block, it works fine..

Why can't I use the DataTable outside of the DataView using block?

Below is my code:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolderBody" runat="Server">    
    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlEstNo1"></asp:DropDownList>    
    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlEstNo2"></asp:DropDownList>
</asp:Content>


protected void bindDDLs(string vCat, int year, int month)
{
    using (DataTable dt = getData(vCat, year, month))
    {

        // THIS CODE ALSO WORKS..
        //ddlEstNo2.DataSource = dt;
        //ddlEstNo2.DataTextField = "estNo";
        //ddlEstNo2.DataValueField = "estNo";
        //ddlEstNo2.DataBind();
        //ddlEstNo2.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Any--", ""));
        //ddlEstNo2.Items.Remove("Summary");

        using (DataView dv = dt.DefaultView)
        {
            // populate ddlEstNo1
            ddlEstNo1.DataSource = dv;
            ddlEstNo1.DataTextField = "estNo";
            ddlEstNo1.DataValueField = "estNo";
            ddlEstNo1.DataBind();
            ddlEstNo1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Any--", ""));
            ddlEstNo1.Items.Remove("Summary");

            // THIS CODE ALSO WORKS..
            //ddlEstNo2.DataSource = dt;
            //ddlEstNo2.DataTextField = "estNo";
            //ddlEstNo2.DataValueField = "estNo";
            //ddlEstNo2.DataBind();
            //ddlEstNo2.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Any--", ""));
            //ddlEstNo2.Items.Remove("Summary");
        }

        // populate ddlEstNo2 ==>>> doesnt work!
        ddlEstNo2.DataSource = dt;
        ddlEstNo2.DataTextField = "estNo";
        ddlEstNo2.DataValueField = "estNo";
        ddlEstNo2.DataBind();
        ddlEstNo2.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Any--", ""));
        ddlEstNo2.Items.Remove("Summary");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

actually your second using statement somehow canceling the effect of first one......so what you can do is this

```
     using (DataTable dt = getData(vCat, year, month))
  using (DataView dv = dt.DefaultView)
        {

            // THIS CODE ALSO WORKS..
            //ddlEstNo2.DataSource = dt;
            //ddlEstNo2.DataTextField = "estNo";
            //ddlEstNo2.DataValueField = "estNo";
            //ddlEstNo2.DataBind();
            //ddlEstNo2.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Any--", ""));
            //ddlEstNo2.Items.Remove("Summary");



                // populate ddlEstNo1
                ddlEstNo1.DataSource = dv;
                ddlEstNo1.DataTextField = "estNo";
                ddlEstNo1.DataValueField = "estNo";
                ddlEstNo1.DataBind();
                ddlEstNo1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Any--", ""));
                ddlEstNo1.Items.Remove("Summary");

                // THIS CODE ALSO WORKS..
                //ddlEstNo2.DataSource = dt;
                //ddlEstNo2.DataTextField = "estNo";
                //ddlEstNo2.DataValueField = "estNo";
                //ddlEstNo2.DataBind();
                //ddlEstNo2.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Any--", ""));
                //ddlEstNo2.Items.Remove("Summary");


            // populate ddlEstNo2 ==>>> doesnt work!
            ddlEstNo2.DataSource = dt;
            ddlEstNo2.DataTextField = "estNo";
            ddlEstNo2.DataValueField = "estNo";
            ddlEstNo2.DataBind();
            ddlEstNo2.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Any--", ""));
            ddlEstNo2.Items.Remove("Summary");

        }
```